# Convolution Estimate

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convolution

I was encountered with a problem about convolution but I think there must be something wrong.

Problem: Suppose that $f,g\in L^{1}(T=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$, prove that
$$\|\int _T f(x-y)g(y)dy\|_{\infty}\leq\|f\|_1\|g\|_1.$$

But I tried to integrate this convolution on T and get
$$\int_T\int _T |f(x-y)g(y)|dydx=\int _T |g(y)|dy\int_T|f(x-y)|dx=\|f\|_1\|g\|_1.$$

If the problem is wrong, how can we get the continuity of the convoluion?

if $f,g\in L^1(T)$, can we prove that
$$\int_Tf(x-y)g(y)dy$$ is a continuous function of x?

I know it is true if $f\in L^1$ and $g\in L^{\infty}$.

Comment: You cannot split the integral like that! The integral on the right depends on $y$ still

Comment: @qbert I think I can do this by integration by substitution.

Comment: If $f,g \in L^1$ then $f\ast g\in L^1$ but in general $f \ast g \not \in L^\infty$. You meant $|\int_T f\ast g(x)dx| \le \|f\|_1\|g\|_1$ using Fubini to change of the order of integration.

Comment: @reuns Thank you, so maybe the question is wrong. But I have another question that if $f,g\in L^1$, can we get the continuity of the convolution? This is the next part of this problem.

Comment: Continuous functions on $T$ are bounded

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(y)=1/\sqrt y$ for $0<y<1,$ $f=0$ elsewhere. Then $f\in L^1.$ Degine $g=f.$ For small $x<0,$ we have

$$f*g(x) = \int_0^{1+x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y-x}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\,dy.$$

As $x\to 0^-,$ the last integral converges to

$$ \int_0^{1}\frac{1}{y}\,dy=\infty$$

by the monotone convergence theorem. Hence the convolution is not bounded. This also shows the convolution is not continuous.